# How to detect Ghostery?

Tags: adblock, livechat

I want to start out by saying we aren't trying to deceive anyone. A lot of these types of questions are met with responses like "*Why don't you just be honest with your users? Why do you need to do this?*"

We use LiveChat on our site, and we've been getting a lot of feedback from users who use AdBlock and Ghostery that our chat isn't working. We want to simply add a Google Analytics event that logs

1. If livechat didn't initiate and
2. if the user is using an ad blocker.

This way we have some stats as to what percent of our users are affected.

We already have it set up to read AdBlock and AdBlock Plus, and it is working well, but we can't seem to find a way to detect Ghostery as well. Has anyone had success with this?

Comment: I'm 100% sure nobody spots your question with the current tags. You surely use JavaScript (so tag it), and you could surely include part of your code for demonstration. Or better: the code that you wanted to work, but failed with.